# DES encryption using openSSL in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to use openSSL for encryption and decryption using DES, decryption is working fine but encryption is not working

The output string generated by the **encryption method** is different than what we gave to the **decryption method**

```
function decrypt()
{
        $password         = 'thisIsASecretKey';
        $encryptedString  =  'YbpeWd70LAxTCQvZjNlnwQ=='; // sample
        $opensslDecrypt   = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedString),'DES-ECB', $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, '');  
        print("\nThe plain: ".$opensslDecrypt);  // OUTPUT :- 123123123
}

function encrypt()
{
    $password         = 'thisIsASecretKey';
    $plainString  =  '123123123'; // sample
    $opensslDecrypt   = openssl_encrypt(base64_encode($plainString),'DES-ECB', $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, '');  
    print("\nThe plain: ".$opensslDecrypt);  // Expected OUTPUT :- YbpeWd70LAxTCQvZjNlnwQ==
}
```

Comment: `encryption is not working` is not enough, what makes you conclude that it isn't working?

Comment: the output string generated by the encryption method is different than what we gave to the decryption method

Comment: `decrypt()` doesn't work for me

Comment: try now please.

Comment: I already found the issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the `encrypt()` function:

```
openssl_encrypt(base64_encode($plainString),'DES-ECB', $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, '')
```

`base64_encode()` is at the wrong place, it should be used on the value returned by `openssl_encrypt` like this:

```
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainString,'DES-ECB', $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, ''));
```

This way the raw data is converted to base64 as the `decrypt()` function expects a base64 encoded string.

Comment: SO really just a typo

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wouldn't consider this a typo